# Parse an xml document with "dynamic" nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am parsing XML via an `XDocument`, how can I retreive all languages, i.e `<en>` or `<de>` or `<CodeCountry>` and their child elements?

```
<en>
  <descriptif>In the historic area, this 16th century Town House on 10,764 sq. ft. features 10 rooms and 3 shower-rooms. Period features include a spiral staircase. 2-room annex house with a vaulted cellar. Period orangery. Ref.: 2913.</descriptif>
  <prox>NOGENT-LE-ROTROU.</prox>
  <libelle>NOGENT-LE-ROTROU.</libelle>
</en>
<de>
  <descriptif>`enter code here`In the historic area, this 16th century Town House on 10,764 sq. ft. features 10 rooms and 3 shower-rooms. Period features include a spiral staircase. 2-room annex house with a vaulted cellar. Period orangery. Ref.: 2913.</descriptif>
  <prox>NOGENT-LE-ROTROU.</prox>
</de>
...
<lang>
  <descriptif></descriptif>
  <prox></prox>
  <libelle></libelle>
</lang>
```

Comment: sometimes I have <En> or <de> or<es> , l must have all langues , <lang> is dynamic balise

Comment: Are all the **<lang>** node in the xml root? Is there any **<lang>** sibling that isn't a **<lang>**?

Comment: I've pulled the text of your question up above the code block, this makes it easier for answerers to scan the question and think about an answer - it's a technique called Bottom Line Up Front.  Hope it helps you get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As your xml document is not well formatted, you should first add a root element.
You may do something like that.

```
var content = File.ReadAllText(@"<path to your xml>");
var test = XDocument.Parse("<Language>" + content + "</Language>");
```

Then, as you have "dynamic top nodes", you may try to work with their children (which don't seem to be dynamic), assuming all nodes have at least a "descriptif" child. (If it's not "descriptif", it may be "prox" or "libelle") **.

```
//this will give you all parents, <en>, <de> etc. nodes
var parents = test.Descendants("descriptif").Select(m => m.Parent);
```

Then you can select the language and childrens.
I used an anonymous type, you  can of course project to a custom class.

```
var allNodes = parents.Select(m => new
            {
                name = m.Name.LocalName,
                Descriptif = m.Element("descriptif") == null ? string.Empty : m.Element("descriptif").Value,
                Prox = m.Element("prox") == null ? string.Empty : m.Element("prox").Value ,
                Label = m.Element("libelle") == null ? string.Empty : m.Element("libelle").Value
            });
```

This is of course not performant code for a big file, but... that's another problem.

---

**
Worst case, you may do

```
var parents = test.Descendants("descriptif").Select(m => m.Parent)
                .Union(test.Descendants("prox").Select(m => m.Parent))
                .Union(test.Descendants("libelle").Select(m => m.Parent));
```